# Python Queue class.. trouble understanding enqueue method

Tags: python, queue, enqueue

So I am trying to learn data structures in python and have moved on to trying to implement a queue. I understand how the data structure works. However I am now defining the enqueue method.

I am learning this on Codecademy btw.

The queue class looks like this:

```py
from node import Node

class Queue:
  def __init__(self, max_size=None):
    self.head = None
    self.tail = None
    self.max_size = max_size
    self.size = 0
    
  # Add your enqueue method below:
  def enqueue(self, value):
    if self.has_space():
      item_to_add = Node(value)
      print("Adding " + str(item_to_add.get_value()) + " to the queue!")
    
      if self.is_empty():
        self.head = item_to_add
        self.tail = item_to_add
      else:
        self.tail.set_next_node(item_to_add)
        self.tail = item_to_add
    
      self.size += 1
    else:
      print("Sorry, no more room!")
    
  def peek(self):
    if self.is_empty():
      print("Nothing to see here!")
    else:
      return self.head.get_value()
  
  def get_size(self):
    return self.size
  
  def has_space(self):
    if self.max_size == None:
      return True
    else:
      return self.max_size > self.get_size()
    
  def is_empty(self):
    return self.size == 0
```

The node class looks like this

```py
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next_node = next_node
    
  def set_next_node(self, next_node):
    self.next_node = next_node
    
  def get_next_node(self):
    return self.next_node
  
  def get_value(self):
    return self.value
```

What I have trouble understanding is the enqueue method specifically this part:

```py
self.tail.set_next_node(item_to_add)
self.tail = item_to_add
```

Why am I setting the tails next node the the node I am adding to the queue?
From what I gather I should set the item_to_add 's next node to be the current tail and then I should say self.tail_node is now the item_to_add?

Any help greatly appreciated as I am quite new to the data_structures and algorithms aspect of things.

Comment: Have you tried drawing it? It often helps a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enqueue, you are appending the node to the end. In the example you have stated, the queue's current last node is `tail` (accessed via `self.tail`)

When you enqueue to this queue, the current tail becomes the second to last node rather than the last. Hence, we do `self.tail.set_next_node(item_to_add)`. This is because the current last node (i.e the tail)'s `next` reference is Null. You update it to the `item_to_add`, which will be the new last node and then change `self.tail` to `item_to_add` to indicate this is the new tail/last node.